# Inconsistent panel border width when exporting as SVG with Cairo

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, svg, cairo

I am generating figures for a paper in svg format, and when I export the ggplot to .svg, I obtain inconsistent panel border widths depending on the device I use to export. I need to use CairoSVG as some figures have symbols that the standard device does not generate properly.

It does not depend on the data, so here I am showing some dummy examples.

```
figure = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
         geom_point()

ggsave(figure, filename = "./output/figure.svg", 
       width = 2, height = 2)
ggsave(figure, filename = "./output/figure_cairo.svg", 
       device = CairoSVG, width = 2, height = 2)
```

Output from default svg device:
[image]
Output from CairoSVG device (as you can see, bottom and right borders are wider):
[image]

The weird thing is that when I edit the CairoSVG output, select the panel and Ungroup the elements, the panel border width becomes consistent. However, the line width is thicker than when using the "default" svg device.
[image]

Can anyone guess why is this happening and if there is anyway of not having to manually edit the figures after exporting?

It does not happen with pdf/CairoPDF though:

```
ggsave(figure, filename = "./output/figure.pdf", 
       width = 2, height = 2)
ggsave(figure, filename = "./output/figure_cairo.pdf", 
       device = cairo_pdf(), width = 2, height = 2)
```

[image]

Here is my sessionInfo in case it helps:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19043)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] Cairo_1.5-12.2  forcats_0.5.1   stringr_1.4.0   dplyr_1.0.7     purrr_0.3.4     readr_2.0.1     tidyr_1.1.3    
 [8] tibble_3.1.2    ggplot2_3.3.5   tidyverse_1.3.1 biomaRt_2.48.3 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bitops_1.0-7           fs_1.5.0               lubridate_1.7.10       bit64_4.0.5            filelock_1.0.2        
 [6] progress_1.2.2         httr_1.4.2             GenomeInfoDb_1.28.1    tools_4.1.1            backports_1.2.1       
[11] utf8_1.2.1             R6_2.5.1               DBI_1.1.1              BiocGenerics_0.38.0    colorspace_2.0-2      
[16] withr_2.4.2            tidyselect_1.1.1       prettyunits_1.1.1      bit_4.0.4              curl_4.3.2            
[21] compiler_4.1.1         cli_3.0.1              rvest_1.0.1            Biobase_2.52.0         xml2_1.3.2            
[26] labeling_0.4.2         scales_1.1.1           rappdirs_0.3.3         systemfonts_1.0.2      digest_0.6.27         
[31] rmarkdown_2.10         svglite_2.0.0          XVector_0.32.0         htmltools_0.5.1.1      pkgconfig_2.0.3       
[36] dbplyr_2.1.1           fastmap_1.1.0          rlang_0.4.11           readxl_1.3.1           rstudioapi_0.13       
[41] RSQLite_2.2.7          generics_0.1.0         farver_2.1.0           jsonlite_1.7.2         RCurl_1.98-1.3        
[46] magrittr_2.0.1         GenomeInfoDbData_1.2.6 Rcpp_1.0.7             munsell_0.5.0          S4Vectors_0.30.0      
[51] fansi_0.5.0            lifecycle_1.0.0        yaml_2.2.1             stringi_1.7.3          zlibbioc_1.38.0       
[56] BiocFileCache_2.0.0    grid_4.1.1             blob_1.2.2             parallel_4.1.1         crayon_1.4.1          
[61] Biostrings_2.60.1      haven_2.4.3            hms_1.1.0              KEGGREST_1.32.0        knitr_1.33            
[66] pillar_1.6.2           GenomicRanges_1.44.0   stats4_4.1.1           reprex_2.0.1           XML_3.99-0.6          
[71] glue_1.4.2             evaluate_0.14          modelr_0.1.8           png_0.1-7              vctrs_0.3.8           
[76] tzdb_0.1.2             cellranger_1.1.0       gtable_0.3.0           assertthat_0.2.1       cachem_1.0.5          
[81] xfun_0.24              broom_0.7.9            AnnotationDbi_1.54.1   memoise_2.0.0          IRanges_2.26.0        
[86] ellipsis_0.3.2
```

Comment: If I use your code I don't get a border at all. Did you forget to include the theme settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might just be because of how devices handle clipping masks. If you want the more consistent behaviour, you can try turning of the clipping for panels altogether. Below; a demonstration of how that affects the look of  borders.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA,
                                    size = 5))

p
```

[image]

```r
p + coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>