# Turning off clipping for ggplot2 figures, but keep the thinner border drawing style?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I lately encountered formatting issues where some of my figures with clipping turned off, have different border linewidth compared to other figures. This can be seen in figure illustrations from multiple questions:

1. [Tick marks misaligned with panel in ggplot2 [R]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638055/tick-marks-misaligned-with-panel-in-ggplot2-r)
2. [Inconsistent panel border width when exporting as SVG with Cairo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69050651/inconsistent-panel-border-width-when-exporting-as-svg-with-cairo)

My question is, how can I keep the border linewidth consistent when clipping is turned off, compared to figures with clipping is on (default)? My base_line_width is set to 9/14, and when I try to specify that for figures with clipping turned off,
`panel.border = element_rect(linewidth = 9/14, inherit.blank=TRUE)`
the border is still thicker.

Finally, why is clipping causing inconsistent border width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding using half of the line width when clipping is turned off should do the job, i.e. if clipping is turned "on" then half of the border line is clipped off.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) +
  geom_point()

p1 +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_rect(
      colour = "black", fill = NA,
      linewidth = 9 / 14
    )
  )
```

[image]

```r
p2 +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off") +
  theme(
    panel.border = element_rect(
      colour = "black", fill = NA,
      linewidth = 9 / 14 * .5
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you1 Do you know why is it the case -- why does clipping setting affect the border linewidth? I'm still a bit puzzled.

Comment: The border line is centered on the position of the panel border. Hence, with `clip = "on"` the half of the border line which falls outside of the panel border gets clipped off. Might be a bad design decision or ... but that's how it is.